# How do I Know if I'm Dead?

Tags: die2nite

I've been playing [Die2Nite](http://www.die2nite.com/) for 3 days now, and still have basically no idea where to find many of the game's various notifications and alerts.  So, following this trend, how will I know when I'm dead?  Where will this be listed?  I haven't got much longer to live, and would like to know where to look to hear the good news.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get a quite obvious notification, the next time you log in. Borrowing from [our Die2Nite chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103/die2nite):

[image: You are DEAD!]

(Yes, I stole once. What of it?)

Comment: Well, that's easy to miss...

Comment: True. It was only after I started to be ignored on the forums that I noticed. ;-)