# What happens when you die in Die2Nite?

Tags: die2nite

What happens when you die in Die2Nite?

Do you spawn the next day in another village?

Comment: See also [How do I Know if I'm Dead?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/11455/56)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, when you login the next day, you will be told you have died, and you may then reincarnate into a new town.  You can also wait to join your next town, for instance if you want to try to join with a friend.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a hero and you die and then don't pick a town, it will not use any of your hero days.